# How to get data from a joined table which contains data from the base table that is going to be updated?

Tags: sql, db2, sql-update, ibm-cloud, exists

I have the following code which updates a base table ORDERS_REPORT_BASE with information joinning HOTLINKS. The update has to happen when

1) SCAC in HOTLINKS matches any of the STD_CARR_CD columns in ORDERS_REPORT_BASE (STD_CARR_CD or STD_CARR_CD_EV_CDC or STD_CARR_CD_CUS or STD_CARR_CD_EV_CUS)

--> 1a If STD_CARR_CD_EV_CUS has a value then it disregards all the others and uses it. If STD_CARR_CD_CUS has value and EV_CUS is NULL then it uses it...and so on

2) CARR_TRACKING_NUM or ACTUAL_TRACKING_NUM are not null depending on the case

It seems 2) works based on the results, however, 1) fails when going thru every CASE as when it finds the STD_CARR_CD, if it does not match, it does not go to the subsequent scenario.

This is the code that works but it is not considering if the SCAC exists previously

```
UPDATE GDTS.ORDERS_REPORT_BASE BASE SET BASE.HOTLINK = 
CASE WHEN BASE.CARR_TRACKING_NUM_CDC IS NULL AND BASE.ACTUAL_TRACKING_NUM IS NULL THEN NULL 
WHEN BASE.CARR_TRACKING_NUM_CDC IS NOT NULL AND BASE.ACTUAL_TRACKING_NUM IS NULL THEN TRIM(HOT.URL1) || TRIM(BASE.CARR_TRACKING_NUM_CDC) || TRIM(HOT.URL2) 
ELSE TRIM(HOT.URL1) || TRIM(BASE.ACTUAL_TRACKING_NUM) || TRIM(HOT.URL2) END
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT SCAC, URL1, URL2 FROM GDTS.HOTLINKS) HOT WHERE 
(TRIM(HOT.SCAC) = CASE WHEN BASE.STD_CARR_CD_EV_CUS IS NOT NULL
THEN BASE.STD_CARR_CD_EV_CUS
WHEN BASE.STD_CARR_CD_CUS IS NOT NULL AND BASE.STD_CARR_CD_EV_CUS IS NULL 
THEN BASE.STD_CARR_CD_CUS
WHEN BASE.STD_CARR_CD_EV_CDC IS NOT NULL AND BASE.STD_CARR_CD_CUS IS NOT NULL AND BASE.STD_CARR_CD_EV_CUS IS NULL
WHEN BASE.STD_CARR_CD IS NOT NULL AND BASE.STD_CARR_CD_EV_CDC IS NULL AND BASE.STD_CARR_CD_CUS IS NULL AND BASE.STD_CARR_CD_EV_CUS IS NULL
THEN BASE.STD_CARR_CD END)
```

In this scenario the HOTLINK field is not updated as the STD_CARR_CD_CUS is not blank but the match does not bring up any result ('MARUUN' is no SCAC in HOTLINK table)

[image: no update as the match does not bring result]

[image: no MARUUN record in the HOTLINK table]

It should have ended up matching with STD_CARR_CD which is not null (UPS value)

I tried adding an EXISTS clause at every HOT.SCAC equals so it also checks that the SCAC is found in the table

```
...
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT SCAC, URL1, URL2 FROM GDTS.HOTLINKS) HOT WHERE 
(TRIM(HOT.SCAC) = CASE WHEN BASE.STD_CARR_CD_EV_CUS IS NOT NULL AND EXISTS (SELECT DISTINCT SCAC FROM GDTS.HOTLINKS WHERE TRIM(HOT.SCAC) = BASE.STD_CARR_CD_EV_CUS)
THEN BASE.STD_CARR_CD_EV_CUS
...
```

However this addition ended up in a duplicity error. Seems there were several rows retrieved from BASE table to update for the whole result.

> Error: [IBM][CLI
>   Driver][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL0788N  The statement was not processed
>   because a row of target table \"GDTS.ORDERS_REPORT_BASE\" was
>   identified more than once for update, delete or insert. 
>   SQLSTATE=21506

Key in ORDERS_REPORT_BASE is PO_ID but in order to match with HOTLINKS table I need to use any of the STD_CARR_CD vs SCAC

I would need to check that any of the STD_CARR_CDs exists in the HOTLINKS table for the CASE to consider it to create the match logic. If it is not there (like the image example) it should go to the other CASE statement.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a merge to update or insert or delete. Perhaps you can try that to achieve what you are trying to do.

```
MERGE INTO target_table AS target
USING (

VALUES (1, 2, 3),
       (4, 5, 6),
       (7, 8, 9)
        -- more rows
        -- Or even you can use a complex join that gives the data set you want to alter
    ) AS source (C1, C2, C3)
    ON target.key_to_match = source.key_to_match
    WHEN MATCHED AND tab.C1 != source.C1 -- or any other condition if needed
    THEN UPDATE SET target.C1 = source.C1,
                   target.C2 = source.C2,
                   target.C3 = source.C3
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (C1, C2, C3)
        VALUES (source.C1, source.C2, source.C3)
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. My concern is that using MERGE allows me to just define 1 ON clause and my goal is to define 4 possible scenarios. If key in target table does not match with key in source table, then I should look for another column in target table, to see if that matching can be possible.

Comment: You can use the case statement inside the merge. For example :
`MERGE into TARGET_table T USING (SELECT CASE WHEN ... THEN ... WHEN ... THEN END AS col1 FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.keycol1=t2.keycol2) S
ON T.key_to_match = S.key_to_match;`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to check the existance of the SCAC on each CASE statement with

```
...
TRIM(HOT.SCAC) IN (SELECT SCAC FROM GDTS.HOTLINKS)
...
```

Thanks!